# post form_data data with alamofire not work

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i want to send data and image from my apps
but not send with this code

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
                "latitude" : lat as AnyObject,
                "longitude" : lng as AnyObject,
                "lokasi" : txtAlamat.text as AnyObject,
                "keterangan" : txtKeterangan.text as AnyObject,
                "jenis_absen" : absenIndex as AnyObject
            ]
            let requestUrl = "https://link.co/link_me"

            Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).authenticate(user: username!, password: password!).responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                if let error = response.error{
                    self.hideLoading()
                    _ = SweetAlert().showAlert("Warning", subTitle:error.localizedDescription, style: AlertStyle.error, buttonTitle:"Dismiss")
                    return
                }
                debugPrint(response.result.value!)
                let parsedResult = JSON(response.result.value!)
```

in postman success send data with form_data
[image]

and i want to add image to, but i don't know how

this print(parameter)
[image]

Comment: What headers you are passing, and you dont need to force cast your variables if its already `AnyObject` or use `Any` instead.

Comment: in headers i passing Authorization.

Comment: what my misstake?

Comment: Please post what you're getting as the response in your application.

Comment: To pass images, you need to pass them as Data. You can refer to this link to get an idea - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832092/how-to-send-image-as-parameters-param-with-post-with-afnetworking

Comment: in my application data not send to server, but authentication success

Comment: not error in my application, but data don't send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to send parameters and data (like an image for example), you MUST use an UPLOAD request *(Alamofire.upload(...))*, instead of the regular request.

The Upload request uses NSData (bytes) to fill the request body, so you'll have to serialize the parameters and the image in the **multipartFormData** body.

I hope this helped you a little bit, to clarify the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, you are posting data with optional so do unwrap you data.

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "latitude" : lat as! AnyObject,
            "longitude" : lng as! AnyObject,
            "lokasi" : (txtAlamat.text)! as! AnyObject,
            "keterangan" : (txtKeterangan.text)! as! AnyObject,
            "jenis_absen" : absenIndex as! AnyObject
        ]
```

Comment: authorization success, but data still not send to link,

Comment: can you print(parameters) before requestUrl initialization and show me ?

Comment: api you are requesting ia using SSL certificate  have you implemented ssl validation ? at your side i mean mobile side ?

Comment: i have update my question and add print parameter photo

Comment: why your post data have a comma after  before ending square bracket ?

Comment: i don't know, but it's from print

Comment: can you help me

Comment: yes sure ... try passing static address  like  "lokasi" : "Indonesia"
and check if it works

Comment: have you implemented ssl certificate at mobile side ? or not because the server you are trying to access is using ssl certificate.

Comment: i have an answer, using multipartformdata